# How to fix broken dependencies?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I Have a broken package system. I have tried `sudo apt get install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Output of said commands:

```
pyotr@pyotr-275e5e-275e4e:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for pyotr: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dvgrab ftplib3 libquicktime2 libsdl-image1.2 libtar0 linux-headers-4.4.0-34
  linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-34-generic
  vgrabbj
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libc6-dev-i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 103 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 1 264 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6 936 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev-i386 amd64 2.23-0ubuntu4 [1 264 kB]
Fetched 1 264 kB in 0s (1 469 kB/s)        
(Reading database ... 290034 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-dev-i386 (2.23-0ubuntu4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/bits', which is also in package libc6-dev-amd64:i386 2.23-0ubuntu4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6-dev-i386_2.23-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
pyotr@pyotr-275e5e-275e4e:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libc6-dev-x32:
 libc6-dev-x32 depends on libc6-dev-i386 (= 2.23-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package libc6-dev-i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libc6-dev-x32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-5-multilib:
 gcc-5-multilib depends on libc6-dev-i386 (>= 2.11); however:
  Package libc6-dev-i386 is not installed.
 gcc-5-multilib depends on libc6-dev-x32 (>= 2.11); however:
  Package libc6-dev-x32 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc-5-multilib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-multilib:
 gcc-multilib depends on gcc-5-multilib (>= 5.3.1-3~); however:
  Package gcc-5-multilib is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc-multilib (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6-dev-x32
 gcc-5-multilib
```